# Cannot find etc/default/tomcat7 to edit AUTHBIND=YES

Tags: linux, tomcat, port

I want to make tomcat work on port 80. I read about this online and found a solution which says to edit server.xml file and then edit etc/default/tomcat7, un-comment AUTHBIND= and make it yes. I did the first but I cannot find etc/default/tomcat7 file. My tomcat is installed inside dspace folder.

Comment: did you ever find it. if you have place comment.

Comment: Still no luck I'll put a comment as soon I find it.

Comment: i guess your getting as much trouble as I am to get your webapp to work on port 80 and not 8080?

Answer (score 0):

Try use This to search for File :

```
sudo find / -type f -name "tomcat7"
```

you must find this path on result :

```
/etc/default/tomcat7
```

use :

```
sudo nano /etc/default/tomcat7
```

to edit File.

Answer (score 0):

Install Tomcat using `apt-get` from Ubuntu repository: `apt-get install tomcat7`.

Then `etc/default/tomcat7` folder will be created after installation.